# How to use the phonon-vlc-backend in PyQt4 on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt4, vlc, phonon

I'm helping develop a PyQt4.8 application which amongst other things plays video and audio. We are using Phonon for this, part of the reason being that we also embed videos in a `QtWebkit` page which uses the same.

On Windows 7, the default phonon backend (`phonon_ds94.dll`) seems to struggle with some media formats (refusal to play) so we're looking to try the `phonon_vlc` backend instead.

[This page](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=83285) appeared to be the most helpful, but I still haven't had success.
I've extracted [phonon_vlc.dll](http://winkde.org/pub/kde/ports/win32/repository-4.5/kde/phonon-vlc-vc90-0.3.1-1-bin.tar.bz2) and copied it into `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\phonon_backend\` . I've installed VLC 1.1.7. I've removed `phonon_ds94`.

But when I run my app, I just get the error:

```
WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
```

I've also tried adding `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC` to the `%PATH%`, but still no joy.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: It's possible that the KDE `phonon_vlc.dll` is compiled against a different version of Qt and that is why it fails to load. Also, I think `phonon_vlc.dll` may depend on other DLLs as well (`libvlc.dll`, `libvlccore.dll`). I haven't managed to get it to work myself either (I'm using PySide but it shouldn't make much of a difference)